# Cannot Import Maven Dependency in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, dji-sdk

I am new to DJI android application development. I have matrice 100. I have followed the step mentioned in

https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration

But I cannot find dji sdk when I search. What am I missing or what am I doing wrong?

Cannot find dji sdk

[image]

Comment: did u add the dependency in the gradle file and sync it and then check

Comment: Please add your build.gradle

Comment: add this line to gradle file dependency  compile 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.3.0'

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.dji:dji-sdk:4.3.0'
}........... I add the above line.. now it shows. Do i need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

i have exactly the same problem. The DJI Android Tutorials are sometimes quite difficult to understand.

I found an older tutorial on gitbooks. 
https://dji-dev.gitbooks.io/mobile-sdk-tutorials/content/en/Android/ImportAndActivateSDKInAndroidStudio/ImportAndActivateSDKTutorial_en.html

But the next issue i had is to finde the real Android SDK File. If you are using the Button "Download Android Mobile SDK V4.3.2" on https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/downloads/ it sends you to github to download the big DJI App Sample.

I hope someone can tell us where to finde the real Android SDK File and how we can integrate it in our Android Project.

Comment: It works! I can create my own DJI SDK App. But only when i try the app on my android device the App register the sdk successfully. When iam using the android studio emulator the app says "register sdk failed, check if network is available". Can someone tell me why and how i can fix it?